# In Google Sheets, for =countifs condition, countif column in another column

Tags: google-sheets

| Team | Oppo | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ATL | BOS |  | BOS | BOS, NYK |  |
| ATL | NYK |  | NYK |  |  |
| ATL | SAS |  |  |  |  |
| ATL | MIL |  |  |  |  |
| ATL | NYK |  |  |  |  |
| ATL | LAL |  |  |  |  |
| ATL | LAC |  |  |  |  |
| CHI | BOS |  |  |  |  |
| CHI | LAL |  |  |  |  |

We have a table of this format in google sheets, and we need to put an equation in cell
F1 that is the count of rows (using columns `Team`, `Oppo`, i.e. `A` and `B`) that are the count of rows where `Team == "ATL"` and `Oppo in D`. For the latter condition, we can likewise use the equation `Oppo in E1` where `E1` is a string concatenation of column `D`.

`=countifs("sheet!A:A", "ATL", "sheet!B:B", __heres the part needed__)`, using two ranges and two criteria, however I am not sure how / if it's possible to do the second criteria for the `value in column D, in cell E1` criteria. Is this possible in Google Sheets?

The output should be 3 as there are three rows (1, 2, 5) where both conditions are met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do that:

```cpp
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A2:A,"ATL",B2:B,TOROW(D2:D,1)))
```

[image]

We are essentially counting each condition individually

[image]

F1 is the count of A2:A="ATL" and B2:B="BOS"

G1 is the count of A2:A="ATL" and B2:B="NYK"

And then we are summing them. In this context `SUMPRODUCT()` is just a shorter way of writing `SUM(ARRAYFORMULA())`

Comment: yes this does seem to do the trick

Comment: this same approach doesn't seem to work for sumifs()? For example if column C was a column of integers, and then we replace countifs() with sumifs(0 and add C2:C as the first parameter to sumifs() @z..

Comment: SUMIFS doesn't work with array formulas, you can concatenate the conditions and use SUMIF or use SUMIFS with the MAP function to iterate over each value.